# String tokenizer in php

Tags: php, tokenize

I've a strange problem that I faced recently.
I've the following code to tokenize string in php:

$token = strtok($string, "#");

```
while ($token != false)
{
    echo $token;
    $token = strtok("#");

}
```

The simple problem I've got is that I'm parsing file which contains many numbers, so in this case 0 will be read as false. So, parsing can't be completed.

What should I do?

Comment: I got the solution here  http://uk.php.net/strpos

Comment: How can that be the solution?

Answer (score 7):

You should use the [**`!==`** operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), to compare `$token` to `false` :

```
while ($token !== false)
```

If you read the manual page of [**`strtok()`**][2], you'll see the following note *(quoting)* :

> This function may return Boolean
> `FALSE`, but may also return a
> non-Boolean value which evaluates to
> `FALSE`, such as `0` or `""`.
>
> Please read the section on
> [Booleans](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) for more information.
> Use [the `===` operator](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) for
> testing the return value of this
> function.

Using `!==` instead of `!=` will make sure there is no type-conversion done.

For instance, `0 == false` ; but `0 !== false`.